# Merge this data

Tags: perl

I am trying to merge names in column B that are associated with column A. So basically for all the columns in column A that have the same group number, I want to merge the names from column B seperated by a comma and space to another file.

```
col A  col B

group1 ashlyn
group3 brooke
group2 caleb
group1 cali
group2 darlene
group2 dixie
group3 daniel
group1 edward
group3 ethan
group2 felix
group2 francis
group1 gabriel
```

to

```
group1 ashlyn, cali, edward, gabriel
group2 caleb, darlene, dixie, felix, francis
group3 brooke, daniel, ethan
```

I tried this

```
open FH, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
open FH2, '>', 'file2.txt' or die $!;

@array = <FH>;

foreach $item (@array){
($group, $name) = split/ /, $item;
print FH2 "$group $name";
}
```

Comment: All your code does is copying the first 2 cols into a new file, inefficiently. Do you have any idea what data structure could be suitable here?

Comment: Ahh I see that I just copied the same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a Hash of Arrays (HoA) here.

- See [How do I make a hash of arrays?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1977)

First loop over your file splitting each line on whitespace. `\s`. You can then take the value of column A and use this as your hash key, using the [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) function to add the value of column B to your array. Finally use the `join` function to make your comma seperated list.

Also use `strict` and `warnings`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

open my $F1, '<', 'file.txt' or die "failed $!"; 
open my $F2, '>', 'file2.txt' or die "failed $!";

my %hash;
while (<$F1>) {
   my($grp, $name) = split /\s+/;
   push @{ $hash{$grp} }, $name; 
} 

for (sort keys %hash) {
  say {$F2} "$_ ", join ', ', @{$hash{$_}};
}
```

Or you could use:

```
while (<$F1>) {
   push @{ $hash{$1} }, $2 if /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;
}
```

Output (`file2`):

```
group1 ashlyn, cali, edward, gabriel
group2 caleb, darlene, dixie, felix, francis
group3 brooke, daniel, ethan
```

Comment: Just like print, but implicitly appends a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Store your data into a hash-of-arrays data structure (see [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %data;
while (my $item = <DATA>) {
    my ($group, $name) = split /\s+/, $item;
    push @{ $data{$group} }, $name;
}

for my $group (sort keys %data) {
    print $group, ' ', join(', ', @{ $data{$group} }), "\n";
}

__DATA__
group1 ashlyn
group3 brooke
group2 caleb
group1 cali
group2 darlene
group2 dixie
group3 daniel
group1 edward
group3 ethan
group2 felix
group2 francis
group1 gabriel
```